# How to convert 9v to 3.3v and 5v?

Tags: voltage, batteries, resistors, esp8266

I am very new to electronics and hardware.

I want to know how can i convert 9v to 5v and 3.3v using only resistors ?

Basically, this is what i am trying to do - 
I want to supply power (3.3v) to an [esp 12e](http://www.amazon.in/ESP8266-ESP-12E-Serial-Wireless-Transceiver/dp/B00RJJHWLA?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=17f5ca63-0641-4785-97ce-5c94fe07507b).
And, i want to supply power (5v) to a soil moisture sensor.
(The soil moisture sensor will be connected to the esp module.)

But, i have only one 9v battery to supply power to both.

I want to do this using resisitors.
Is it possible ?
If yes, how ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to do it using resistors only, this question belongs on puzzling.stackexchange because it's just a mental puzzle, not actual engineering. If you want to do it with real parts, use two LM317 circuits, which should be readily available everywhere.

Comment: you are looking for voltage divider  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider . here is calculator to divide voltage with resistor http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/voldiv.html

Comment: Don't expect to get much run time out of a 9volt battery.  That module draws around 300mA of current.  A typical 9Volt alkaline battery has a capacity of around 550mAh so don't expect more than maybe an hour of operation on a new battery.  It'll probably be much less because linear regulators waste a lot of power.  It'll work longer with a switching regulator, but don't expect miracles.

Answer (score 14):

Resistors are the wrong way to do what you want.  Step back to your actual problem, leaving out how you think it should be solved.

There are basically two reasonable approaches to making 3.3 V and 5 V power from 9 V.  These are a *linear regulator* and a *buck converter*.

A linear regulator is like a self-adjusting series resistor.  It keeps the output voltage constant despite varying input voltage.  These things are simple, cheap, robust, and widely available.  The drawback is that their input current is the same as their output current, so this current times the voltage drop from input to output is burned up as heat.  For small currents, this inefficiency is often worth the simplicity.  For example, your 5 V moisture sensor probably takes very little current.  A industry standard 7805 5 V linear regulator may be appropriate for it.

A buck converter is a more sophisticated circuit that is a type of switching power supply.  Instead of the input current being the output current, the input power is the output power (plus a little for inefficiency).

These become more attractive for higher powers and higher voltage drops for two reasons.  First, since they don't burn up the voltage drop times the current as heat, there is less heat to get rid of.  That is usually the driving reason since dealing with the heat is costly and takes physical space.  The second reason is to conserve power, like when a battery is used.

A buck converter is probably appropriate for making the 3.3 V from 9 V.  The voltage drop is larger and the current probably higher than the moisture meter.

For example, is you need 100 mA at 3.3 V, a linear regulator would draw the same 100 mA from the battery.  That's 900 mW coming from the battery.  Of that, (9V - 3.3V)*100mA = 570 mW will go to heating the regulator, and the remaining (3.3 V)(100 mA) = 330 mW will actually be delivered to the circuit.  The overall efficiency is only 37%.

In contrast, let's say a buck regulator is 85% efficient at dropping 9 V to 3.3 V.  The load requires 330 mW, so it will take (330 mW)/85% = 388 mW from the battery.  The current drain on the battery will only be (388 mW)/(9 V) = 43 mA.  Note that this is less than half of the battery drain resulting from using a linear regulator.

Comment: Don't you have a typo for either of the efficiency values for the buck, in the last paragraph?

Comment: @Mist: Good catch.  Fixed.

Comment: Awesome! Great explanation for a newbee like me.  How would you determine the type of buck converter to buy for a given project?

Comment: @Ray: Just go thru listings on a distributor or vendor site to find whatever is most suitable for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible using resistors.

*Is there a downside ?*

Yes because a resistor divider is not "smart", it will only provide for example 3.3 V when the current taken by the load (the esp12) is **constant**. Unfortunately that current is **not constant**.

*But you said it is possible*

Yes if you **waste** a lot of current then the voltage variation can be made small. But it is inefficient, it will drain your battery very quickly. Ergo: **not a good solution**

*What is better then ?*

There are voltage regulator chips like LM317, 78L05, LM1117. The LM1117 comes in different versions including 3.3 and 5 Volt version. The LM1117 is also reasonably efficient and cheap. **I would use an LM1117 !** To learn more how to use an LM1117, read the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm1117.pdf).